# Integrating Paymetric.com within a website

Tags: payment-gateway, payment, payment-processing, payment-services

Has anyone ever integrated paymetric within a website, using any language (PHP, java, .Net)? I need to integrate paymetric with our new website, but I can't find any help on the web. Your quick help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Paymetric has APIs to integrate their payment system into your own application or website. Here are some example they listed on their website:
https://www.paymetric.com/integrations/

There seems to be one project on github:
https://github.com/lalitkaushik/paymetric

Comment: I'm not able to see any APIs docs on the page, can u help, please? 
And also is it possible to integrate it with Shopify, by maintaining its existing integration with SAP? As I'm building Shopify/SAP integration app.

Comment: @RahulRaval Paymetric's docs are only available on request usually from the person that created an account with them. I have not seen it freely shared online.